# Organizing helpers in sub-directories

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-helper

I am new to CakePHP and I had trouble organizing my helper files.  I searched through the web and doesn't seem to find an answer for this.

I have no problem using the helpers if I put them under app/Views/Helpers/test.

But when I put it under app/Views/Helpers/Global/test,

and

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $helpers = array('Form', 'Html', 'Js', 'Time', 'Text', 'Session','Global/testHelper');
```

I get a "Cannot redeclare class testHelper"

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Don't user controllers typically extend the AppController?  Are you editing Cake's files?

Comment: I am editing AppController to include the helper to ALL controllers. just like what the cookbook suggested

Comment: No..I am not manually including the helper class..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to organize and package your code is using [Plugins](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html).

You cannot have subfolders under your app's Helpers directory. But you can use [App::build()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#adding-paths-for-app-to-find-packages-in) to specify alternate locations for your helpers.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self explanatory. You can not literally call your helper `TestHelper`, as that name is already taken by the CakePHP Test Suite (defined in `lib/Cake/Test/Case/View/HelperTest.php`).

Just name your helper something else and you should be fine.

Comment: TestHelper is just an example that I used here.  Sorry it was a bad example, but the real situation I used was SideMenuHelper.  Any ideas on how to use helper classes in subdirectories?  Is it supposed to just work?